# How to load a specific sheet from an excel file by asking the user in R?

Tags: r, excel, worksheet

I would like to load a specific worksheet from an excel file by asking the user.
For example:

```
    Which worksheet do you want to load ?
```

Answer:

```
    SV069_01
```

Then, I would like to read only the table from this SV069_01 sheet to perform the analyses I already wrote in my code. So I would like to associate X with the name the user just entered and make R opening the right worksheet from the excel file. I started something like

```
    IPX <- file.path("donnees/Obritrap_process_compilation_1%.xlsx")
    fun <- function() {
    IPID <- readline("Which IP do you want to analyze?")
    if  (IPID = "SV069_01")
    {tableauIPTAFX <- readWorksheetFromFile(IPTAFX, sheet= "IPID")}
```

I would be grateful if someone has a better and working way to do it ? Thank you.

Comment: Just put `IPID` in `sheet = IPID`.

Comment: As in `sheet = IPID`, not `sheet = "IPID"`. `"IPID"` is just a string, `IPID` is the variable that you stored your user input.

Comment: Not quite, OP needs to append "_01" to the end of the string returned.

Comment: Okay, so now I wrote something that could work, I get this message:Error: IllegalArgumentException (Java): Sheet index (-1) is out of range (0..11), How can I fix it ?

Comment: Sometimes I get this other message: Error: OutOfMemoryError (Java): Java heap space